# How to get the field name in a validation handler?

Tags: 9

I have a custom `class TextWidget extends WidgetBase`

Inside it I have a custom validation handler that looks like this:

```
public function validate($element, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $value = $element['#value'];
  $label = 'This field'; // What method is there to get the human facing field name?
  if (strlen($value) === 0) {
    $form_state->setError($element, $this->t('@label cannot be empty.', ['@label' => $label]));
  }
}
```

It outputs the error "This field cannot be empty." if the field is empty.

I want to replace the static text 'This field' with the actual human facing name of the field.

Is there a public method that lets me do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A class that extends [`WidgetBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21WidgetBase.php/class/WidgetBase/9.3.x) can get the label with `$this->fieldDefinition->getLabel()`. That is used, for example, from [`WidgetBase::form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21WidgetBase.php/function/WidgetBase%3A%3Aform/9.3.x).

```php
$element = [
  '#title' => $this->fieldDefinition->getLabel(),
  '#description' => $this->getFilteredDescription(),
];
```